# Excel, find max value for a collection of sequence

Tags: excel, max, sequential

In column A, I have a collection of sequential data.They all start from 1, but end with different numbers. I wish I can create a column B, which has the max number for each sequence. Is there any formula can help me do this? These numbers are in different cells.eg.A1=1 A2=2 A3=3.....

```
A  123123412
B  333444422
```

Comment: Are these numbers in different cells? I.e. A1 = 123123412 , A2 =  333444422?

Comment: Easy with VBA but assume from tag is must be a formula?

Comment: They are in different cells.They are in different cells. A1=1, A2=2, A3=3,

Comment: Could you please help me write the VBA? I don't have knowledge about it.

Comment: Is the first digit the sequence number or something? Maybe I'm not understanding correctly. Can u give example of input and example of output you would like? Preferably in a screenshot? You can upload to https://imgur.com and link it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers aren't in the same cell and the sequences always start with 1 you can just look for the next 1 in the column and go back 1 (except for the last sequence where you need to find the last number in the column):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$100,MATCH(1,A2:A$100,0)+ROW()-1),LOOKUP(999,A$1:A$100))
```

[image]

This is shorter but has to be entered as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter (CSE):

```
=INDEX(A1:A$99,MATCH(TRUE,A2:A$100<A1:A$99,0))
```

Non-CSE version

```
=INDEX(A1:A$99,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:A$100<A1:A$99,0),0))
```